# Se puede iterar sobre una instancia de un modelo en Django 3

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente

En el template, la variable `object_list` es un objeto QuerySet de un modelo cualquiera y `object` seria su correspondiente instancia del modelo de la base de datos.

Luego esto seria el listado de los registros

```
    {% for object in object_list %}
       <ul>
         <li>{{ object }}</li>
       </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

Ahora, si para cada objeto quiero mostrar todos los valores de su campos
¿Cómo debo realizar el bucle `for` iterando sobre la variable `object`?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes transformar el queryset en un diccionario con [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values) y luego [iterar sobre clave/valor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for). Prueba algo como esto:

```
{% for item in object_list.values %}
   <ul>
     {% for key, value in item %}
     <li>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
     {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Asi tal cual esta, me da el siguiente error: Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 9. 
Modificando el bucle for mas interno por :{% for value in item.values %} puedo mostrar los valores del registro, pero desafortunadamente ya no dispongo del objeto del modelo, es decir, la variable item no puede aplicar los metodos del modelo, por ejemplo __str__

Comment: perdón, creo que sería `for key, value in item.items`. Si te funciona esto último actualizo la respuesta. Ver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018973/how-to-iterate-through-dictionary-in-a-dictionary-in-django-template